# Is there an equivalent to pythons's SequenceMatcher in SQL Server to join on columns that are similar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequencematcher

In python there a nice built in function that lets me check the difference between the sequence of two strings. Example below:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similar(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
```

Example:

```
similar("Apple","Appel")
0.8
similar("Apple","Mango")
0.0
```

Is there an equivalent function in SQL?

What I need to do is join two tables on a column. On table A, this column is their actual account number, on the other table the column is the user adding their account number which isn't a required field and because of that I've noticed that there are slight variations in their actual account number.

Table A

```
account_num   Name
5WWW55        John
DDDDD7        Jacob
SSSSX7        jingleheimer
```

Table B

```
account_num   Name
5WWW55        John
3SSSX7        jingleheimer     -- First character is different 


Select Table_A.account_num, 
       Table_b.Name 
FROM Table_A
JOIN TABLE_B 
          on Table_A.account_num = Table_B.account_num
```

Expected output:

```
account_num   Name
5WWW55        John
SSSSX7        jingleheimer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`DIFFERENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/difference-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT Table_A.account_num, 
       Table_b.Name 
FROM Table_A
JOIN TABLE_B 
  ON DIFFERENCE(Table_A.account_num , Table_B.account_num) = 4;
```

**[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f965777da5ffcb309a6acb19cb89bddb)**

Answer (score 0):

Levenshtein distance might be what you are looking for. I've used it before to compare similarity between strings in SQL server.